# Restricting section of XSLT to single node

Tags: xslt

Is there a way of restricting a section of XSLT to a single node, so that the entire path of the node is not necessary each time?

For example...

```
Name: <xsl:value-of select="/root/item[@attrib=1]/name"/>
Age: <xsl:value-of select="/root/item[@attrib=1]/age"/>
```

This could be done via a for-each command, but I am led to believe that these should be avoided if at all possible...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/item[@attrib=1]"/>
  Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  Age: <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I guess I'm asking if there is an XSLT equivalent of the VB.NET With command?

I would prefer to avoid xsl:template for readability, as the XSLT file in question is large, but happy to accept if that is the only way to do it.  And if so, what is the syntax to call a particular template based on specific node?

**Update**

In follow up to the answer by @javram, it is possible to match separate templates based on particular attributes / nodes.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/item[@attrib=1]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/item[@attrib=2]"/>

<xsl:template match="/root/item[@attrib=1]">
  Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  Age: <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/item[@attrib=2]">
  Foo: <xsl:value-of select="foo"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se with using `xsl:for-each` as you are doing here. In this case, it functions fine in a "with" sort of way. People counsel against using `xsl:for-each` to explicitly loop over something when XSLT provides better ways to do the equivalent, such as letting templates apply and match.

Comment: Downvoter... can I ask why, and after so long?

Comment: Downvoter... no I didn't think so... you just hide behind the anonymity of SO, rather than be constructive. Thanks, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to use a template:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/item[@attrib=1]"/>

.
.
.

<xsl:template match="/root/item">
     Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
     Age: <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Although it's not as visually nice as a "With" type block, I think you're right that this is the correct way of doing it.  As follow on questions are not allowed via comments, would you be kind enough to show how you would match to a different template if the @attrib was changed?  I will update my question to reflect this request

Comment: Please ignore the follow up question, it was rather easier than I thought, I have updated my question appropriately

Comment: In your follow up update,  you could have also done: <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/item"/> which would have saved a line of code.  Since the attribute was already included in the separate match criteria,  both templates would still be hit.

Comment: this is true, but it would not guarantee the order they were output... my example makes sure @attrib=1 is output before @attrib=2 even if the XML has the data the other way around

Answer (score 2):

You may use variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="/root/item[@attrib=1]" />

<xsl:value-of select="$foo/name" />
<xsl:value-of select="$foo/age" />
```

Comment: I had no idea that variables could also hold nodes, thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 another possible style is:

```
<xsl:value-of select='/root/item[@attrib=1]/
                       concat("Name: ", name, " Age: ", age)'/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we're still on 1.0, and the block the "With" covers is far too big for "concat" to be useful.  But I appreciate the input, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/item[@attrib=1]"/>
  Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  Age: <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

descends into all nodes (each matching node, one by one).

This:

```
<xsl:for-each select="(/root/item[@attrib=1])[1]"/>
  Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  Age: <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

descents into first (possibly only) matching node and is equivalent of VB.NET `With` statement as you wished.